# How to join the same table multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to join the same table multiple times; 
for example, suppose that there are those two tables:

```
employee(ssn, lname, fname)
document(document_name, employee_ssn, manager_ssn)
```

and here, I want to get employee and manager names for each document, so I would expect the results like below:

```
doc_name | e_lname | e_fname | m_lname | m_fname
   A     | lname1  | fname1  | lname2  | fname2
   B     | lname3  | fname3  | lname4  | fname4
```

and so on.

So what I did was like the below:

```
select 
    d.doc_name, e1.lname, e1.fname, e2.lname, e2.fname
from document d
join employee e1 on (e1.ssn = d.employee_ssn)
join employee e2 on (e2.ssn = d.manager_ssn)
```

But this gives the results like below:

```
doc_name | e_lname | e_fname | m_lname | m_fname
   A     | lname1  | fname1  | lname1  | fname1
   A     | lname1  | fname1  | lname2  | fname2
   B     | lname3  | fname3  | lname3  | fname3
   B     | lname3  | fname3  | lname4  | fname4
```

How do I join the same table multiple times to get the expected results?

Comment: Is `doc_name` unique in `document`?  Is `ssn` unique in `employee`?  If so then you shouldn't be getting duplicates like this.

Comment: Oh, I see. The doc_name is not unique in the table, so that was the reason. Thank you.