# SQL name instead of ID in many to many relation

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to make simple chat with database. So I created 2 tables:

1. `Users` (ID(PK), Name, Password)
2. `Messages` (ID(PK), senderID(FK from users), recipientID(FK from users)), text

I am really noob in SQL and I just can't write query that will return table `Messages` but with normal names instead of senderID and recipientID. Also I didn't find examples where 1 table uses twice, so JOIN didn't work for me, or I used it in wrong way.

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: You got your answer, but you could've gotten the answer with a little more searching... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702120/how-to-join-the-same-table-multiple-times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT US.Name as SenderName, UR.Name as RecipientName, M.text
FROM Messages M JOIN Users US ON US.ID = M.senderID
  JOIN Users UR ON UR.ID = M.recipientID
```

Comment: Omg, just join twice, thank you alot,  i am epic nooobb =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, or which db you are using but this is what I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT Messages.text, Users.name
FROM Messages 
inner JOIN Users
ON Messages.sender_id = Users.id
```